# How can I do a groupby list comprehension in Python (coming from a C#/LINQ perspective)

Tags: c#, python, linq

I'm trying to switch over to using python exclusively. Something that I have used pretty extensively in C# is LINQ. In this exercise the goal is to get a collection of key value pairs, the keys being each month and the value a count of the number of messages in that month, how can I do something like this with python or perhaps what would be a better way to do this?

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        string[] months = { "jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", "jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec" };

        var log = LineReader ();
        Dictionary<string, int> cumulativeMonths = new Dictionary<string, int> ();

        months.ToList ()
            .ForEach (f => {
                cumulativeMonths.Add(f, log.GroupBy(g => g.Split(' ').First().ToLower())
                    .Where(w => w.Key == f).ToList().Count());

            });                                         
    }
    public static IEnumerable<string> LineReader()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Hello World!");
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader (File.OpenRead ("/var/log/messages"))) {

            while (!sr.EndOfStream) {

                yield return sr.ReadLine ();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test Input:

```
Feb 18 02:51:36 laptop rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.4.2" x-pid="2952" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Feb 18 02:51:36 laptop kernel: Adaptec aacraid driver 1.2-0[30300]-ms
Feb 18 02:51:36 laptop kernel: megaraid cmm: 2.20.2.7 (Release Date: Sun Jul 16 00:01:03 EST 2006)
Feb 18 02:51:36 laptop kernel: megaraid: 2.20.5.1 (Release Date: Thu Nov 16 15:32:35 EST 2006)
Feb 18 02:51:36 laptop kernel: megasas: 06.805.06.00-rc1 Thu. Sep. 4 17:00:00 PDT 2014
Feb 18 02:51:36 laptop kernel: qla2xxx [0000:00:00.0]-0005: : QLogic Fibre Channel HBA Driver: 8.07.00.16-k.
Feb 18 02:51:36 laptop kernel: Emulex LightPulse Fibre Channel SCSI driver 10.4.8000.0.
Feb 18 02:51:36 laptop kernel: Copyright(c) 2004-2014 Emulex.  All rights reserved.
Feb 18 02:51:36 laptop kernel: aic94xx: Adaptec aic94xx SAS/SATA driver version 1.0.3 loaded
Feb 18 02:51:36 laptop kernel: ACPI: bus type USB registered
```

Test Output would be a dictionary: 
{Jan: 64562, Feb: 38762} ....

Comment: can you add some test input and expected output?

Comment: just updated, I probably should have noted the values in the dictionary will be a count of all messages in the log for each key (month)

Answer (score 2):

This is easier than you've done it, and very easy in Python:

```
with open('/var/log/messages', 'r') as f:
    cumulative_months = {}
    for line in f:
        key = line.split()[0].lower()
        cumulative_months[key] = cumulative_months.get(key, 0) + 1
```

`with` is similar to C#'s `using` and will close the file when it goes out of scope.  The python file object can be used as an iterator.  It will read and return a line at a time until it hits EOF. (It actually reads a little more than one line, see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects)).

Alternatively, as noted by m.wasowski, you can use the `collections.Counter` class for this type of task to make things even easier *and faster*.

Comment: Nice, I'll try this the only problem I'm thinking is also that I need to rely on a line at a time, because readlines() would read the whole file which could be a few gigs into memory

Comment: @PadraicCunningham interesting, I hadn't used it like that before, does it read the whole file or just a bit at a time?

Comment: @PaigeThompson, you never need readlines in python unless you actually want  a list, you can iterate over the file object getting a line at a time, a file object in python returns it's own iterator

Comment: To clarify, it iterates over one line at a time, but [there may be more than one line stored in the buffer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29133556/does-for-line-in-file-read-entire-file).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) dict:

```
from collections import Counter
with open('yourfile') as f:
    count = Counter (line.split()[0] for line in f)
```

Sorry for any mistakes, it is written from mobile :)

Comment: some explanation would not hurt

Comment: Not when you type on phone. And if I start my box and start SO and python... you know how it is going to end, don't you? Feel free to add your answer, I'll be happy to +1 it... tomorrow. Goodnight!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah that is esesntially what I came up with myself, I guess I was wondering if there was a more elegant (one-linerish) approach to solving the problem:

```
fh = open("/var/log/messages", encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
fh.seek(0)
febMessages = [x for x in fh if x.split(' ')[0].lower() == 'feb']
len(febMessages)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your own answer you can simply use sum and a generator expression if all you want is the count for february:

```
with open("/var/log/messages") as f:
    febMessages = sum(x.split(None, 1)[0].lower() == 'feb' for x in f)
```

`x.split(None, 1)` splits once on whitespace and extracts the first element, we generate a value at a time using the generator expression so we don't create a full list of elements to just throw away and sum sums all the times `(x.split(None, 1)[0].lower() == 'feb'` evaluates to True.
You also don't need `fh.seek(0)`, the pointer is at the start of the file when you open it.

If you actually want a count of all months stored then use a Counter dict.