# Does it takes RAM to save a readlines array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, file

I am using the command `lineslist = file.readlines()` of a 2GB file.

So, I guess it will create a *lineslist* array of 2GB or more size. So, basically is it the same as `readfile = file.read()`, which also creates *readfile* **(instance/variable?**) of 2GB exactly?

Why should I prefer readlines in this case?

Adding to that I have one more question, it is  also mentioned here https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html:

> readline(): a newline character (\n) is left at the end of the string, and is only omitted on the last line of the file if the file doesn’t end in a newline. This makes the return value unambiguous;

I don't understand the last point. So, does `readlines()` also have unambiguous value in the last element of its array if there is no `\n` in the end of the file?

We are dealing with combining the files (which were split on the basis of blocksize) So, I am thinking of choosing readlines or read. As the individual files may not be end with a `\n` after splitting and if `readlines` returns unambiguous values, it would be a problem, I think.)

PS: I haven't learnt python. So, forgive me if there is no such thing as instances in python or if I am speaking rubbish. I am just assuming.

EDIT:

Ok, I just found. It's not returning any unambiguous output.

```
len(lineslist)
6923798
lineslist[6923797]
"\xf4\xe5\xcf1)\xff\x16\x93\xf2\xa3-\....\xab\xbb\xcd"
```

So, it doesn't end with '\n'. But it's not unambiguous output eiter.

Also, no unambiguous output with `readline` either for the lastline.

Comment: Yes, it takes RAM to save both `readlines` and `read`(both read whole to memory). Use `for line in file` if memory is an issue. [This](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.nl/2013/06/readlines-considered-silly.html) page discourages the use of readlines. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246260/python-readlines-usage-and-efficient-practice-for-reading) also looks at something similar.

Comment: @M.T Hi, thanks. This is exactly what I am looking for. These links are helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your issue correctly you *just* want to combine (ie concatenate) files.

If memory is an issue normally `for line in f` is the way to go.

I tried benchmarking using a 1.9GB csv file. One possible alternative is to read in large chunks of the data which fit in memory.

Codes:

```
#read in large chunks - fastest in my test
chunksize = 2**16
with open(fn,'r') as f:
    chunk = f.read(chunksize)
    while chunk:
        chunk = f.read(chunksize)
#1 loop, best of 3: 4.48 s per loop

#read whole file in one go - slowest in my test
with open(fn,'r') as f:
    chunk = f.read()
#1 loop, best of 3: 11.7 s per loop

#read file using iterator over each line - most practical for most cases
with open(fn,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        s = line
#1 loop, best of 3: 6.74 s per loop
```

Knowing this you could write something like:

```
with open(outputfile,'w') as fo:
    for inputfile in inputfiles: #assuming inputfiles is a list of filepaths
        with open(inputfile,'r') as fi:
            for chunk in iter(lambda: fi.read(chunksize), ''):
                fo.write(fi.read(chunk))
            fo.write('\n') #newline between each file(might not be necessary)
```

Comment: Hi, actually, no issue with memory. But, using read using chunksize instead of readlines seems to be a proper solution if file parsing is not required

Answer (score 1):

`file.read()` will read the entire stream of data as 1 long string, whereas `file.readlines()` will create a list of lines from the stream.

Generally performance will suffer, especially in the case of large files, if you read in the entire thing all at once. The general approach is to iterate over the file object line by line, which it supports.

```
for line in file_object:
    # Process the line
```

As this way of processing will only consume memory for a line (loosely speaking) and not the entire contents of the file.

Comment: Hi, but it do need memory to save the whole array instance right? I am not able to figure it out correctly

Comment: In this case, I feel that, using readline in a for loop is preferable than readlines, though it is slow. Does it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, readlines() causes reading all file to variable.
Much better it would be to read file line by line:

    `f = open("file_path", "r")
    for line in f:
        print f`

It will cause loading only one line to RAM, so you're saving about 1.99 GB of memory :)

As I understood You want to concatenate two files.

    `target = open("target_file", "w")
    f1 = open("f1", "r")
    f2 = open("f2", "r")
    for line in f1:
        print >> target, line
    for line in f2:
        print >> target, line
    target.close()`

Or consider using other technology like bash:

    `cat file1 > target
    cat file2 >> target`

Comment: can we use cat if the files are parts of a binary file?

Comment: AFAIK yes. Cat is not interpreting content, it's just reading input and passing it to output.