# Unable to split the sequence from a Fasta File

Tags: python-2.7, fasta

my fasta file has multiple sequences like the following

> ```
> >header1
> MPANFTE
> GSFDSSG
> >header2
> MDNASFS
> EPWPANA
> ```

so I am writing a code to remove the headers and the output looks like this in a temporary file:

> MPANFTEGSFDSSG
>
> MDNASFSEPWPANA

So far, I have come up with this code: but it is not giving me the exact output.

```
import sys,subprocess

# open the file
my_file = open("gpcr.fasta")
# read the contents
my_gpcr = my_file.readlines()
for line in my_gpcr:
    if '>' == line[0]:
        header = line
    else:   
        tempf = open('temp.fasta', 'w')
        tempf.write(header)
        tempf.write(line)
        tempf.close()
        print line
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that what you want to do is to print a file containing only one line per sequence? You can use an awk script:

```
awk 'BEGIN{newline=0}{if(/^>/){if(newline==1){print ""} newline=1}else printf $i}END{print }' gpcr.fasta
```

If you want to use Python, anyway, this is how I would do it:

```
import sys, re

# open the file                                                                                            
my_file = open("gpcr.fasta")

newline = 0
for line in my_file:
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    if re.match('>', line):
        # after we read the first header, we will print a new line when we see one to separate concatenated sequences                                                                                                   
        if newline == 1:
            print
        newline = 1
    else:
        sys.stdout.write(line)

print
```

Also, a header starting with '>' is not a real FASTA header. Only > should be at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Thank you so much, now it's working. And yes it doesn't start with '<' , I was unable to type this in stackoverflow, it was showing something different.

Comment: No need for `re`, `line.startswith('>')` is totally sufficient. If you rearrange the two `if` blocks in one `if/else` block you can save one `re.match` which makes the code easier to read and faster.

Answer (score 0):

- No need for `import sys,subprocess` in this snippet
- You never `close my_file`, you can avoid this by using `with open("gpcr.fasta") as my_file:`
- Every new sequence line overwrites the previous one since you open `temp.fasta` with `'w'`, you could either append the sequences by opening the file with `'a'` or using the header as the filename.
- You read the whole file at once with `readlines()`, that's convenient for small files but slow and consumes a lot of memory for larger files (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246260/python-readlines-usage-and-efficient-practice-for-reading) for a detailed discussion). It is faster to iterate on the `file` object.

So here is the suggested code:

```
my_file = 'gpcr.fasta'
header = ''

with open(my_file, 'r') as my_gpcr:
    for line in my_gpcr:
        if line.startswith('>'):
            # check if we already passed the first line
            if header:
                tempf.close()
                print()
            header = line.strip()
            # open a new file for each sequence
            tempf = open('{}.fasta'.format(header[1:]), 'w')
            # remove if you want to skip the header
            tempf.write(header)
        else:
            # write the sequence line to the file
            # remove the strip() if you want to keep the line breaks
            tempf.write(line.strip())
            # end='\r' makes the sure the sequences are concatenated
            print(line.strip(), end='\r')
```

Note: This assumes a correctly formatted FASTA file.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

Is this all you're trying to do?

```
$ awk '/>/{if (NR>1) print ""; next} {printf "%s", $0} END{print ""}' file
MPANFTEGSFDSSG
MDNASFSEPWPANA
```