# Loading Python list from file

Tags: python, list, file

I have `list.txt`. This file consist from strings:

```
name1
name2
name3
name4
name5
...
```

On disk file space near 196 MB.

But after loading it into memory:

```
L = []
F = open('list.txt')
L = F.readlines()
F.close()
```

he placed there 1,3 GB.

Please tell why there is so huge difference between on-disk file and his copy in list structure in RAM?

Running with Python 2.7 on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Did you think you got all those fancy objects for free?

Comment: Read up on this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246260/python-readlines-usage-and-efficient-practice-for-reading)