# Python: iteratively add to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have the following code:

```
for state in state_list:
    state_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for df in pd.read_csv(tax_sample,sep='\|\|', engine='python', dtype = tax_column_types, chunksize = 10, nrows = 100):
        state_df = pd.concat(state_df,df[df['state'] == state])
state_df.to_csv('property' + state + '.csv')
```

My dataset is quite big, and I'm breaking it into chunks (in reality these would be bigger than 10 obs). I'm taking each chunk and checking if the state matches a particular state in a list, and, if so, store it in a dataframe and save it down. 
In short, I'm trying to take a dataframe with many different states in it and break it into several dataframe, each with only one state and save to CSV.

however, the code above gives the error:

> TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you
>   passed an object of type "DataFrame"

Any idea why?

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: You may want to read how `pd.concat()` works. You call it incorrectly.

Comment: `pd.concat(state_df,df[df['state'] == state])` should be `pd.concat([state_df,df[df['state'] == state]])`, notice the argumnt passed in `[]` so that it is a list of dataframes.

Comment: Somewhere it is written on Pandas Stone Tablets: [Never call DataFrame.append or pd.concat inside a for-loop. It leads to quadratic copying.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36489724/1422451)

Answer (score 0):

Consider [iterating off the chunks](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-chunking) and each time run [`.isin[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) for filter on *state_list* but save in a container like dict or list. As commented, avoid the overhead of expanding dataframes in a loop.

Afterwards, bind with `pd.concat` on container and then run a looped `groupby` on *state* field to output each file individually.

```
df_list = []

reader = pd.read_csv(tax_sample, sep='\|\|', engine='python', 
                     dtype=tax_column_types, chunksize=10, nrows=100)

for chunk in reader:
   tmp = chunk[chunk['state'].isin(state_list)]    
   df_list.append(tmp)

master_df = pd.concat(df_list)

for g in master_df.groupby('state'):
    g[1].to_csv('property' + g[0] + '.csv')
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I don't quite understand what is happening in the above. I see that we are reading the file in in chunks, such that "reader" contains 10 chunks. But how does this reduce the amount of memory required? Isn't is all still stored in memory, but just in multiple dataframes?

Comment: Did you attempt the code and test performance? If you read the link, you avoid the memory footprint of reading entire data file all at once. It is akin to python's [readlines() vs looping over read object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17246300/1422451) of text files. The memory efficiency issue is not the size of data held in RAM but when/how the OS allocates RAM for data.

Comment: Yes, I've tried running it and it still throws a memory issue. I'm breaking into chunks of 1,000, and there are a couple of million rows.

Comment: At what line does the memory issue raise? Check by commenting out lines. What if you just ran `reader=`? Then the `for chunk` loop? I wonder if `pd.concat()` is the issue or even `groupby()`. Try also running at command line and not any IDE (Spyder/PyCharm).

Comment: Busy running it now, thanks, will let you know where I run into issues

Comment: just finished running it now. It is the 'tmp =chunk...' line that is crashing it

Comment: If I understand the code you provided correctly, isn't every row still being stored in the master_df dataframe, rather than separate dataframes being created for each state?

Comment: No that `tmp` line filters rows with `isin` and appends filtered dataframe to list. Otherwise, I advise storing data in a database like opensource SQLite. Import a state table, index various columns for quick table scans, and run join query on large table, then import result into pandas. See its `read_sql` method.